# Problema com Rota e IF no Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma Rota que passa 2 parâmetros, sendo que podem ser opcionais.

Na view, Se clicar no Link 1 (passa os 2 id's) quero que filtre certas opções. Se clicar no Link 2 (vai passar apenas 1 id), se clicar no Link 3 (vai passar o outro id) se clicar no Link 4 (não passa nenhum para buscar todos os registros) Na mesma View sempre.

as Rotas estão assim:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'site'], function () {

// Rotas simples do Site

Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/institucional', 'SiteController@institucional')->name('institucional');
Route::get('/consultoria', 'SiteController@consultoria')->name('consultoria');

Route::get('/seja-revendedor', 'SiteController@revendedor')->name('seja-revendedor');
Route::post('/seja-revendedor/confirmacao', 'SiteController@revendedorSalvar')->name('seja-revendedor.confirmacao');

Route::get('/menus', 'SiteController@menu')->name('menus');

// Rotas dos Cursos
//Route::get('/cursos/{id_categoria_curso?}/{id_atuacao_area?}', 'SiteController@cursosFiltro')->name('cursos');

Route::get('/cursos', 'SiteController@cursosFiltro')->name('cursos');

//Rota para Campo Busca
Route::post('/cursos/busca', 'SiteController@busca')->name('curso.busca'); });
```

e o Controller está assim:

```
public function cursosFiltro(Request $request){

    // Lista Cursos, Categorias, Modalidades e Áreas de Atuação
    $categorias = CategoriaCurso::all();
    $modalidades = EnsinoModalidade::all();
    $areas = AtuacaoArea::all();

    $id_atuacao_area = $request->id_atuacao_area;
    $id_categoria_curso = $request->id_categoria_curso;


    if ($request->query('id_categoria_curso') and $request->query('$id_atuacao_area')){
        $cursos = Curso::where('id_categoria_curso', $id_categoria_curso)
            ->where('id_atuacao_area', $id_atuacao_area)
            ->get();
    } elseif ($request->query($id_categoria_curso)){
        $cursos = Curso::where('id_categoria_curso', $id_categoria_curso)->get();

        return view('site.cursos.cursos',
            compact('cursos', 'categorias', 'areas'));
    } elseif ($request->query($id_atuacao_area)) {
        $cursos = Curso::where('id_atuacao_area', $id_atuacao_area)->get();

        return view('site.cursos.cursos',
            compact('cursos', 'categorias', 'areas'));
    }

    $cursos = Curso::all();

    return view('site.cursos.cursos',
        compact('cursos', 'categorias', 'areas'));
}
```

o Link está assim:

1 - Onde passa somente um parâmetro:

```
@foreach($areas as $area)
    <a href="{{ url("cursos/$area->id_atuacao_area") }}" class="brk-categories__item">
       <span class="brk-categories__item-name">{{ $area->nome }}</span>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

2 - Onde passa os dois parâmetros:

```
@foreach($categorias as $categoria)
    <li class="brk-nav__children brk-nav__drop-down-effect">
        <a href="#">
            <span>{{ $categoria->nome }}</span>
        </a>

       <ul class="brk-nav__sub-menu brk-nav-drop-down font__family-montserrat">
           @foreach($areas as $area)
               <li class="dd-effect">
                   <a href="{{ url("cursos/$categoria->id_categoria_curso/$area->id_atuacao_area") }}">
                   <span class="brk-header-list__icon">
                       <i class="{{ $area->icone }}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   </span>
                   {{ $area->nome }}
                   </a>
                </li>
           @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Os dois valores não podem ser opcionais se pertencerem à rota... Pois o seu sistema nunca vai saber qual argumento foi ignorado. Uma abordagem bacana para pegar seria o uso de querystrings.

**Editado:** as urls onde você passa parâmetros podem ser montadas assim:

Onde você passa 1 parâmetro:

`<a href="{{ route("cursos", ['id_atuacao_area'=> $area->id_atuacao_area]}}">`

Onde você passa 2 parâmetros:

`<a href="{{ route("cursos", ['id_atuacao_area'=> $area->id_atuacao_area, 'id_categoria_curso'=> $area->id_categoria_curso]}}">`

Sua route ficaria assim:

`Route::get('/cursos', 'SiteController@cursosFiltro')->name('cursos');`

E a sua função iria ficar assim:

```
  public function cursosFiltro(Request $request){
    // Seu código aqui

    if ($request->query('id_categoria_curso') and $request->query('$id_atuacao_area')){
        $cursos = Curso::where('id_categoria_curso', $id_categoria_curso)
        ->where('id_atuacao_area', $id_atuacao_area)
        ->get();
    }
    // Seu código aqui
}
```

A sua função passaria a receber um argumento do tipo `Request`, e você iria acessar os dados da querystring usando `$request->query('id_categoria_curso')`, por exemplo.

Dá uma olhada aqui se quiser ver mais sobre: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Flávio, fiz assim como sugeriu. Só que ai ta dando pagina não encontrada quando passo algum parâmetro. O Link muda alguma coisa?

Comment: Eu recebi os parâmetros assim na Funcão: 
$id_atuacao_area = $request->id_atuacao_area;
$id_categoria_curso = $request->id_categoria_curso;

Comment: Atualiza a questão, e nos mostre o seu arquivo de rotas todo e a URL que você usou. pode ser que, por algum motivo, ele não está caindo na rota criada por você

Comment: Pronto @Flávio Santos, atualizei tudo como vc solicitou!

Comment: O erro está na URL que você está montando. Dessa maneira que eu montei acima, sua URL vai ter o formato de querystring: `cursos?id_categoria_curso=10&id_atuacao_area=15` ao invés de `cursos/10/15`... Eu coloquei os números 10 e 15 como valores de exemplo, mas você substitui esses números pelas variáveis PHP

Comment: @JunioAraujo, atualizei a resposta, com a função route() do laravel, que monta as urls da maneira ideal. Dá uma olhada lá!

Comment: atualizei os arquivos como passou. Agora não renderiza a página. Aparece tudo em branco. Não dá erro mas não carrega nada